# Platform Shield: Can we encrypt/decrypt the data explicitly using tenant secret in apex?

Tags: apex, shield

Is there way to ensure clear text? If it is encrypted can we use the tenant secret to decrypt OR vice versa?

I am trying to explore the apex side offerings of shield if any.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When using Platform Encryption, you must have the “View Encrypted Data” permission to view field values in plaintext.

Comment: Agreed. It works based on permissionSet/profile which is fine.
My scenario was clearly apex based where I am trying to customize OR achieve a conditional encryption ( So far it is not possible with my understanding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not decrypt the data by using the tenant secret via Apex code.Since salesforce itself it will decrypt the data whenever you open the record.

It can be done in case if you are using the third party encryption gateway services.

Comment: Thanks for confirming on apex is not a way to go. 

Yes, I am trying this scenario because of comparison with cipher(3rd party as mentioned)